# Does negative trichotomy hold for constructive ordinals?

Tags: constructive-mathematics, ordinal-numbers

I don't know if there is a standard term for this, but by "negative trichotomy" I mean ¬ (¬  <  ∧ ¬  =  ∧ ¬  < ). This holds for constructive real numbers as an easy consequence of  ≤  ↔ ¬  <  and  =  ↔ ( ≤  ∧  ≤ ) but the ordinal analogue to the former is  ⊆  ↔ ¬  ∈  and I only am aware of a proof of that for the special case of the natural numbers.

One possible literature reference is [https://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~mhe/TypeTopology/Ordinals.Notions.html#is-decidable-order](https://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/%7Emhe/TypeTopology/Ordinals.Notions.html#is-decidable-order) but I don't read agda in general, or TypeTopology in particular, well enough to know whether that is relevant or not.

At the risk of stating the obvious, ¬ (¬  <  ∧ ¬  =  ∧ ¬  < ) is equivalent to ¬ ¬ (  <  ∨  =  ∨  < ) in intuitionistic logic, so the problem can be stated either way.

Comment: nice question !

Comment: Not sure if it is related, but the strength of the  comparability principle for class well orders in second-order set theory (over GBC, for example, with classical logic) is an open question. The issues feel similar.

Comment: Paul Taylor's [Intuitionistic Sets and Ordinals](https://www.paultaylor.eu/ordinals/intso.pdf) suggests this is not possible. See page 18. There's no derivation of some 'taboo' though. Just a statement that the classical proof of trichotomy cannot be adapted even to a double negated version.

Comment: The elementary methods I and my collaborators used to find taboos at places like https://us.metamath.org/ileuni/ordtriexmid.html do not seem obviously applicable (at least, I didn't see how).

Comment: What is the precise definition of $<$ that you're using? The answer might depend on that.

Also, what does the double-negation translation of ZF into IZF get you in this context? Is it $\neg \neg \forall AB \neg\neg(A < B \vee A = B \vee B < A)$?

Comment: Strengthening @JamesHanson's question, which definition of ordinals are you using? There are several constructively inequivalent definitions. After thinking about this for 10 minutes, having an answer for *any* definition would be interesting.

Comment: The answer does NOT seem to be [in this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2208.03844), but it still felt right to reference this jewel of Nicolai Kraus, Fredrik Nordvall Forsberg and Chuangjie Xu (and also Tom de Jong in a follow-up paper). They greatly clarify and explore the relations between several proposals for ordinals. They also study an intriguing form of trichotomy: trichotomy for ordinals which are known to be bounded by a common upper bound.

Comment: The definition of ordinal I have been working with is a class that is transitive and whose elements are transitive (and < is ∈). See https://us.metamath.org/ileuni/df-iord.html including a link to the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy page that I was using as my reference. Obviously the rabbit hole of differing definitions of ordinal is a bit deeper than I realized but I'll accept the David Wärn answer because (assuming Peter LeFanu Lumsdaine's comment that it is indeed about this definition) that answers the question in the negative.

Comment: @ Jim Kingdon: Regarding the equivalence between definitions: The definition used in David Wärn’s answer is, essentially, the “structural”/“foundation-agnostic” way of phrasing the Powell definition that you link.  It’s immediate (just from regularity + extensionality) that any hereditarily transitive set is a transitive, extensional, well-founded relation.  Conversely, if you have enough set theory to do Mostowski collapse (so IZF certainly suffices), then every trans, ext, w-f relation is uniquely isomorphic to some hereditarily transitive set. [cont’d]

Comment: [cont’d] In constructive settings, there really aren’t *enough* such orderings, and this motivates the zoo of other notions of ordinals, whose relationships are rather subtler.  But the equivalence between “hereditarily transitive set” and “trans, w-f, ext’l relation” is straightforward and unproblematic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll assume by ordinal you mean a set with a transitive, well-founded, and extensional relation. Then it's *not* constructively valid that $\neg \neg (A < B \vee A = B \vee A > B)$ for ordinals $A$, $B$. In fact we don't even have $\neg \neg (A \le B \vee A \ge B)$ for all $A$, $B$. To see this, we construct a presheaf topos with two ordinals $A$, $B$ such that $\neg (A \le B)$ and $\neg (A \ge B)$ both hold. Specifically, we look at presheaves on $\omega^{\mathrm{op}}$, i.e. sequences $X_0 \to X_1 \to \cdots$. From the internal perspective, $A$ and $B$ will be downward closed subsets of $\omega$. Indeed any downward closed subset of an ordinal is again an ordinal. Now take $f, g : \omega \to \omega$ to be two increasing functions such that $f(x) < g(x)$ and $f(x) > g(x)$ each happen for infinitely many $x$. We take $A_n$ to be the set $\{ x \in \omega \mid x < f(n)\}$, and $B_n$ to be the set $\{ x \in \omega \mid x < g(n)\}$. We claim that $\neg(A \le B)$ in the internal language of our topos (the other claim is proved the same way). To this end, we have to show that there is no $n \in \omega$ such that $A \le B$ holds at stage $n$. Indeed, if $A \le B$ held at stage $n$, then we would have $\{x \in \omega \mid x < f(m)\} \subseteq \{x \in \omega \mid x < g(m)\}$ for all $m \ge n$. This contradicts the assumption that $f(x) > g(x)$ for infinitely many $x$.

Comment: Very neat! OP’s link in comments to https://us.metamath.org/ileuni/ordtriexmid.html confirms he’s using the Powell definition of ordinal as “hereditarily transitive set”, which under a mild core of set theory matches what you take here. // A very slight rephrasing perhaps makes the countermodel simpler to follow: OP’s “not-not trichotomy” implies “for any down-closed subsets $X,Y \subseteq \omega$, not-not ($X \subseteq Y$ or $Y \subseteq X$)”; then your model is a counterexample to the latter, with $X, Y$ just as subsets of $\omega$ (so we never need to view them as ordinals in the topos).

Answer (score 2):

It's three decades since I wrote *Intuitionistic Sets and Ordinals*, at which time I knew how to express well founded relations as coalgebras, but I had very little understanding of the subject.

In recent years I have come back to this topic and written two substantial draft papers, the second being *Ordinals as Coalgebras*.   So I would encourage people who are interested in constructive or categorical ordinals to look at those works.

Since it's more than three decades since I believed Excluded Middle, I have long since got out of the habit of looking for ways in which the classical ideas might *almost* hold.  Really, constructive mathematics is *much more interesting* when you let it lead you where *it* wants to go, instead of tracking its heresies against classical logic.

However, I would point out that almost all of the (counter)examples in *Ordinals as Coalgebras* appear in the *simplest* non-classical topos, ie presheaves on a single arrow. The classical ideas about ordinals really are *very* fragile.

I do have a constructive result there (Lemma 9.13) that looks a bit like trichotomy: if the join $x\curlyvee y$ exists with respect to the reflexive(-transitive) closure of the well founded relation then $x$ and $y$ are comparable ($x\prec y$ or $x=y$ or $y\prec x$).

However, the purpose of writing that paper was not to give a new "official" account of ordinals using category theory, but to *destroy* the single notion.

The point is that set theory provides *partial* models for the (non-existent) free algebra for the covariant powerset functor.   So there should be *other, different* kinds of ordinals that do the same for other functors and constructions.

See (http://www.paultaylor.eu/ordinals) for all the papers (including the old ones).

Comment: I'm sorry, but, between the various places where you explain that OP was somehow asking the “wrong” question, that everyone who still finds value in the law of excluded middle is an idiot, and that your new way of looking at things is better than the previous one, is there a place where you actually answer the question that was being asked? It's reasonable that you should want to promote your point of view, especially as your work was quoted in the question, but *answers* on MathOverflow are still meant to be *answers*, not explanations of the fact that the question is morally abhorrent.

Comment: I see your point about whether this answers the question but even if it doesn't quite fit the mathoverflow format I am glad to see some references to constructive literature on ordinals in case I do want to dig into this topic more deeply at some point.